# Wmode=transparent and autoplay=1 wont work togather

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, iframe, youtube

I have a player from youtube embeded in html page, which i need to play when page is loaded, and since i have a button to remove the player i need wmode=transparent so i can position elements above it.

This is the code for the player i use:

```
<iframe width="560" height="235" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vUd6TpdFLl4?autoplay=1?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If i use just one of them, they work fine, but if i put them togather none of them works.

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for the url query string is this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="235" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vUd6TpdFLl4?autoplay=1&amp;wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You were adding the second parameter using `?` instead of `&amp;`

Comment: Love you long time men! didn't know that :D. Thanks a lot.